# How many sequences of four numbers exist with these conditions?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

First of all, this may seem very basic for you, but I've never been good at math, and I can't figure this out!

I need to solve the number of sequences that exist under this conditions:

- All sequences are made of four numbers like **0123**
- All the numbers must be **different**
- The **first** and the **last** number are on the **same** horizontal line
- The **second** and *third* numbers are on the horizontal line immediately **above** the first and last number line

> This is table that is provided with the problem

```
[1][2][3]
[4][5][6] 
[7][8][9] 
[-][0][+]
```

How many sequences exist under these conditions?

a) 72

b) 90

c) 162

d) 171

Comment: For example, $4236$ would be allowed since all the numbers are different, $4$ and $6$ come from the second row and $2$ and $3$ come from the row above.  Correct?

Comment: Yes! That is one allowed sequence!

Comment: I might not have understood the problem statement correctly, but this is how I see the problem. The first and fourth digits can only be chosen from lines 2 and 3 since there is only one digit in the last line and there is obviously no line above the first line. 

We can choose a digit from the second line in 3 ways, then choose an item from the first line in 3 ways, then another one from this line in 2 ways and finally we have 2 options for the last digit. Multiplication yields 36 options. Then we have 72 more options if the 1st and 4th digits are chosen from the third line.

Comment: @DonDraper: do you mean $36+72$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, yes, but it seems that this is wrong.

Comment: @DonDraper: maybe you missed the *immediately* constraint.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, exactly, my bad. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As two pairs of different digits must be on the same row, $0$ is excluded.

You can choose the first and last digits freely in the second or third row, which makes $2\cdot3\cdot2$ options, then the second/third digits in the first or second row respectively.

In total,

$$2\cdot3\cdot2\cdot3\cdot2.$$

Comment: Thank you, but can you explain it further? I am really bad at math! How did you arrived into this expression  **2⋅3⋅2** ?

Comment: @AndrejHatzi: try to enumerate the solutions in a systematic way.

Comment: After 2 minutes of thinking about your explanation I could understand it! Thank you very much for your guidance!

Comment: @AndrejHatzi: I preferred to let you think rather than giving a straight answer.

Answer (score 1):

You shall only choose the first and last digit from the **two middle rows**. That's because the bottom row contains only one number and for the top row, there's no row above to choose the second and third digit.

Let's start by choosing two digits from the $3$rd row. We can choose and rearrange two items out of three in $$P(3,2)=\frac{3!}{1!}=6$$ ways. Following the exact same reasoning, for the second and third digit, we have:
$$
P(3,2)=\frac{3!}{1!}=6
$$
ways for the middle digits.

Thus, $6$ ways to choose first and last digits and $6$ ways to choose second and third. That's a total of $36$ ways to choose all $4$ digits.

Also, we could repeat all these actions, choosing the first and last from the $2$nd row and the middle ones from the $1$st one. Again, that's a total of $36$ ways to choose all four digits.

At last, since we can carry out this procedure either the first $36$ ways or the other $36$ ways, the total ways are 
$$
36+36=72.
$$